# why Python3.6,3.5 proxy error,python 3..7,3.8 works well

Tags: python-3.x, pip, proxy

I have a question about Python proxy. I created a C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini file on a Windows system with the following content:

`[global] index-url = https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple proxy = http://127.0.0.1:8101`

It works well for Python 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9. However, when I use pip for Python 3.6 (pip(21.3.1)) and Python 3.5, I encounter a proxy error like this:

For example: py -3.6 -m pip install numpy==xxx

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000014DFC3D1CC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/numpy/
Does anyone know what could be the issue? Thank you!

> =python3.7 works well; python3.6,3.5 proxy error
> and,the way, py -3.6 pip install  --proxy http://127.0.0.1:8101  show the same error~